# Task.Wait error

Tags: c#

I am running a Selenium Test.All the tests are running fine but when I am trying to send the completion mail It is giving error.The code is running fine when I am locally running through VS2015 but returning error when I am running from TeamCity.

I am using C# and Chromedriver as a technology stack.

The code is returning below error.

> Diplomat.Enav.Web.Selenium.Tests.dll: Diplomat.Enav.Web.Selenium.Tests.GlobalFixture 
>   TearDown method failed. One or more errors occurred.
>      at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
>      at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>      at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout)
>      at Diplomat.Enav.Web.Selenium.Tests.Common.Mailer.SendResults(List`1 states, Boolean waitForCompletion) in d:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\a367a3eda4cbbd88\Diplomat.Enav.Web\Diplomat.Enav.Web.Selenium.Tests\Common\Mailer.cs:line 59
>      at Diplomat.Enav.Web.Selenium.Tests.Common.SeleniumStatus.SendCompletionEmail() in d:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\a367a3eda4cbbd88\Diplomat.Enav.Web\Diplomat.Enav.Web.Selenium.Tests\Common\SeleniumStatus.cs:line 182
>      at Diplomat.Enav.Web.Selenium.Tests.GlobalFixture.RunAfterAnyTests() in d:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\a367a3eda4cbbd88\Diplomat.Enav.Web\Diplomat.Enav.Web.Selenium.Tests\Common\GlobalFixture.cs:line 39

The code which is giving this error is

```
Task sendMailTask = smtp.SendMailAsync(message);
if (waitForCompletion)
    sendMailTask.Wait(5000);
```

When it is executing `sendMailTask.Wait(5000)` it is returning error.

Comment: Cant you examine the inner exception? (i.e the actual exception thrown).

Answer (score -1):

try yo use

```
Thread.Sleep(5000);
```

but this is a bad way. Better to wait for some message will be shown on the page.